# Bridge interface has the same MAC as one of the interfaces and thus doesn't work on it

Tags: ubuntu, bridge, netplan

I've moved system ssd from one PC to another. It has 2 network adapters. For some strange reason bridge works with one of them(enp4s0, even though it is listed as DOWN) but not with another one (enp2s0) which MAC address it copied. I also have another pc to compare and i see that bridge there has a unique MAC address and it works.

```
ip -br link show
lo               UNKNOWN        00:00:00:00:00:00 <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> 
enp2s0           UP             00:aa:bb:cc:dd:ee <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
enp4s0           DOWN           bb:ee:dd:aa:cc:00 <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> 
br0              UP             00:aa:bb:cc:dd:ee <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
```

part of netplan config:

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        enp2s0:
            dhcp4: false
            dhcp6: false
        enp4s0:
            dhcp4: false
            dhcp6: false
    bridges:
        br0:
            interfaces: [enp4s0]
```

Also here i see 2 interfaces attached to bridge, maybe thats the problem, why are there two if i have just one in netplan config?

```
brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.503eaa0d526e       no              enp2s0
                                                        enp4s0
virbr0          8000.5254005e079f       yes             virbr0-nic
```

I want bridge to work with enp2s0, since it's a faster of the two. Is there maybe some way to regenerate that bridge, maybe there is some cache settings,i don't know?

Comment: The title is *your* interpretation of the cause. I can just say that for what I know about this topic this is not the cause (even if you see that the MAC is different on systems using recent systemd). But the given information doesn't allow me to help further. I just know "it doesn't work", but not what doesn't work and what are the symptoms when it doesn't work versus when it works.

Comment: @A.B Under enp4s0 internet and local network work, once i switch to enp2s0 as bridge interface network stops working, also internet disappears on other PCs in the network. What can i look at?

Comment: Also internet isn't managed by this PC, there is a router for this.